# lektor server does not start under freebsd

Tags: lektor

I have installed lektor via freebsd ports, there was no error. `lektor quickstart` also created my project but after I would like to start `lektor server` no matter which folder I am in or which flags do I add, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lektor", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('Lektor==3.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'lektor')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lektor/cli.py", line 766, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lektor/cli.py", line 471, in server_cmd
    from lektor.devserver import run_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lektor/devserver.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lektor.admin import WebAdmin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lektor/admin/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .webui import WebAdmin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lektor/admin/webui.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask.helpers import safe_join
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_join' from 'flask.helpers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/helpers.py)
```

I did everything as it was described in quick start, so this is just a default installation. My os version is:

```
FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE releng/13.1-n250148-fc952ac2212 GENERIC amd64
```

And my installed lektor version is:

```
Lektor, version 3.2.2
```

How should I fix this? Is that a known bug? I didn't found anything usefull while googleing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like somebody reported this as a freebsd bug. Appling the fix: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=263922 will update it to new version of lektor and the server will also work.